# How do I empty my browser's cache while my hosting server's cache is still stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

We are utilizing the "MemoryCachingService" with the "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" namespace in my project. I use the '_memoryCache' variable to store certain data. I understand from R&D that it will save server RAM, thus my first concern is: How can 1000 users of a web application distinguish themselves from one another?
2. How is storage organized and maintained?
3. Can I clear it from my browser?

Comment: If you cache per-user lots of users will gobble up your server resources quickly.  (Which is why people try to avoid server-side session vars)  The use-case for this would be for serving all users from a single cache... if that's a common request and is data that doesn't change often and is accessed often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side cache is just a key/value store; since you are using the in-process memory version, this will **consume** server RAM, not "save" it - the point of cache is to reduce costs fetching repeated data, at the expense of holding data somewhere else (usually "cheaper"). It is not isolated by ... anything; if you want per-user data in the cache, you would need to use something unique about the user (their user id, typically) as part of the key, for example `$"/u/{userid}/logical/data/path"` (the key is simply opaque text).

Cache is not in the browser, so I'm not sure what question 3 means.

If you want system-implemented user isolation: maybe consider "session" data instead of cache.

Comment: Marc Gravell, I used to access a web application through system A and use API, which stands for save data in memory cache. and Data from other systems' caches would likewise return if I logged in using the same credentials on systems B or C.  What does it mean? 

and Is it possible to delete the server-side memory cache from browser?


and Can I clear server-side memory cache from the browser?

Comment: the server-side cache **isn't in the browser**; the browser is client-side; it is meaningless to delete a server-side cache from the browser - that's not a thing that exists in the first place, to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Memory Cache and Browser Cache are two different type of Cache

1 : Browser Cache
It Caches some responses and assets based on http configuration on client browser storage and if the condition matches the caching policy, browser get responses from caches on the storage instead of requesting the back-end server

if you clear the browser cache you just removed this type of cache , not the server side cache

For more investigation read [THIS DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) from mozilla

2 : ASP.Net MemoryCache

This type of cache is useful when we want to cache some objects in the RAM and don't want to get it from the source more than once

For example you have a database query that take 10 second to execute and you want to get it from database once and use it as a api response that must take 1 second.

For more investigation about this type of cache read [THIS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory)

Comment: How would it apply if I modified anything straight out of the database? while cache removal time is 6 hours. @Amir Hossein Fakhreddin

Comment: the simple answer is you cant. Modifying database outside of the application is a bad practice, i suggest do all your modification in the application and raise change events that flash the memory catch @ShashankSingh

Comment: "cache"; the word is "cache"